# How to Handle Exception in JavaBeanIntegerProperty

Tags: java, exception, javafx, javabeans

My project is split into two modules:

In **Model** module:
I have a class `SudokuField` that informs `SudokuBoard` when changed. Then, if tips are enabled, `SudokuBoard` throws `SudokuException` with some info if it's not possible to solve Sudoku with inserted value.

`SudokuField` notifying:

```java
public class SudokuField {

    private int value = 0;
    private PropertyChangeSupport notifier;

     public void setValue(int value) {

        if (value < 0 || value > 9) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Number: " + value + "Expected 0-9");
        }

        int oldValue = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        notifier.firePropertyChange("value", oldValue, value);

    }
}
```

`SudokuBoard` throwing:

```java
public class SudokuBoard implements PropertyChangeListener{

    public static final int SIZE = 9;

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) throws SudokuException {
        if (!autoCheck) {
            return;
        }
        if (checkBoard()) {
            return;
        }

        int oldValue = (int) evt.getOldValue();
        int newValue = (int) evt.getNewValue();

        SudokuField field = (SudokuField) evt.getSource();
        int i=0, j=0;
        outerloop:
        for (i = 0; i < SudokuBoard.SIZE; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < SudokuBoard.SIZE; j++) {
                if (this.getField(i, j) == field ) {
                    break outerloop;
                }
            }
        }
        
        throw new SudokuException(
                "Wrong value inserted"
                        + "(old: " + oldValue
                        + ", new: " + newValue + ")",
                        i, j, oldValue, newValue, field);

    }
}
```

In **View** module:
I am using JavaFX, and JavaBean to display and sync `SudokuField` and `TextField`.
Part of my Controller:

```java
public class Window implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private GridPane sudokuPane;

    private final SudokuBoard board = new SudokuBoard(new BacktrackingSudokuSolver());
    private final List<List<TextField>> fields = Arrays.asList(new List[9]);
    private final List<JavaBeanIntegerProperty> integerProperties =
            new ArrayList<JavaBeanIntegerProperty>();
    
    public Window() {
        for (int i = 0; i < SudokuBoard.SIZE; i++) {
            fields.set(i, Arrays.asList(new TextField[9]));
            for (int j = 0; j < SudokuBoard.SIZE; j++) {
                TextField textField = new TextField();
                fields.get(i).set(j, textField);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        StringConverter converter = new IntegerStringConverter();

        for (int i = 0; i < SudokuBoard.SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SudokuBoard.SIZE; j++) {
                //I generate Sudoku board and TextFields in Constructor
                TextField textField = getTextField(i, j);
                SudokuField field = board.getField(i, j);

                JavaBeanIntegerPropertyBuilder builder = JavaBeanIntegerPropertyBuilder.create();
                JavaBeanIntegerProperty integerProperty = null;
                try {
                    integerProperty = builder.bean(field).name("value").build();
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    System.out.println("Ignoring NoSuchMethodException in " + this.getClass());
                }

                //i need to store JavaBeanIntegerProperty, otherwise GarbageCollector
                //destroys my connections
                integerProperties.add(integerProperty);

                //adding textField to GridPane
                sudokuPane.add(textField, i, j);
                textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(integerProperty, converter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now the big question: How to handle those `SudokuExceptions` somewhere in Controller? From this Exception I can easily get any information to modify desired textField however I want, but I can't handle it. I tried adding:

```java
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(Window::exceptionHandler);
//and
Thread.currentThread().setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(Window::exceptionHandler);
```

`exceptionHandler` method in `Window` Controller:

```java
    public static void exceptionHandler(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("working: " + i);
        }

    }
```

in `initialize` and Constructor of Controller and also in `Main` class of **view** module in both `main` and `start` methods, but it's not calling this method(I checked that with `System.out.println`). I don't want to add `PropertyChangeListener` to `SudokuBoard`, because I want to make as little changes as possible to my **Model** module.

Whole project is a project developed as part of classes at my uni.

Comment: curious: why do you mix swing/fx?

Comment: @kleopatra where? I'm not sure, but I think I'm not. At least I can't see any imports in my Controller refering javax.swing package

Comment: ahh .. you are right, my bad _) I mis-formulated, should have been: why do you use old-style javabeans with PropertyChange/Support? There's an impedance mismatch between beans spec properties and fx properties that's hard to handle when mixing them.

Comment: unrelated: re-using class names (f.i. Window) from the framework might confuse future code readers

Comment: So about the PropertyChange, I use it because my lecturer recommended it as the easiest way to do bidirectional syncing. And why my Controller is called Window? Because I randomly picked that name before reading more (I like to make experiments first, then read about stuff I'm doing). Now I would probably use "PrimaryController" or something like this

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found this [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088773) and I think because of this, I can't make what I want. So instead I created my own `ActionEvent` which is "thrown" instead of `SudokuException` in `SudokuBoard` and added `ActionEventListener` interface to my Controller. Maybe it's not the solution that I wanted oryginally, but I think it's prettier. Special thanks to my friend for helping me. I'll leave this question open, because maybe someone know how to get around this Exception Handling problem, and someone else can use this answer.